# Why does Android Studio show different DPI settings for two identical devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm having trouble understanding this weird behavior. In my "Android Virtual Devices" settings, I had two devices that are both 8.0-inch tablets with 800x1280 screen resolution. However, one is categorized as "tvdpi" and the other one is categorized as "mdpi". The only difference is that the "tvdpi" device was created earlier (in Android Studio 2.1 or something) and the "mdpi" device was created in Android Studio 2.3.

[image: Android Virtual Devices settings]

This has created a problem where I can't see what the final layout will look like in the layout editor. When I ran the app on my real device, it's running a layout same as the simulated layout in the "tvdpi" device, but not the "mdpi" device. I'm afraid that if I delete the "tvdpi" device, I will never get it back and my layout editor will forever look different from the real device.

Comment: Are you targeting your app for just a single device (one brand, one exact model)?

Comment: Yes, since this is an internal app and we only have one device to work with. It's Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 8.0 (SM-T360) if you are curious.

Comment: According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), **tvdpi** is for "Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it". So I wonder if it's true that in the new version of Android Studio, tvdpi is no longer created in AVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug report to Google and it's being worked on.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=246595

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not the same device. Note the name column, both devices are called different. They may have the same physical screen size. But the density of each one is different to the amount of pixels.

Comment: The names are different because I named them differently. They both have 800x1280 screen resolution and 8.0-inch screen size, the the density of the two devices should be the same.

Comment: Of course, but in android studio you can set differents dpi for each device

Comment: Actually that's not true. You set the screen resolution and the diagonal size and the DPI is calculated for you. Hence my problem.

Comment: But when you created that's tablets images, you probabily choose one in tvdpi and other in mdpi. Look --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1oPuK07EVQ4U2wzR1Z3WTNzYVU

Comment: Can you show the detailed settings for these two? I haven't found a place to set the dpi manually.

Comment: Did you make that screenshot from [here](http://i.imgur.com/bUvEqyd.png)? Of course a 7-inch screen and and 10-inch screen with the same resolution would have a different dpi. It's not something you can set.

Comment: You can't set dpi manually, you can choose resolution ideal for your project, in base to resolution, android studio generate the dpi, but this will depend on the type of device you are creating, in this case I think it is a tablet.